# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Lockout not activating

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using `PasswordSignInAsync` to verify my users like this:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
```

However, I noticed that I am unable to get locked when I purposely enter the wrong password.

This is my startup.cs:

```
var lockoutOptions = new LockoutOptions()
{
    AllowedForNewUsers = true,
    DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5
};

services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(
    options => {
        options.Lockout = lockoutOptions;
    }
)
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
```

I checked in the database when I purposely enter the wrong password, the `AccessFailedCount` increases by 1 until it hits 5 then it goes to 0 again so that means its actually working. Its just the locking part is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that `LockoutEnabled` is actually `true` on the current users in the database? If it is set to `false`, the user will never be locked.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I config lockout feature in asp.net core 2.2

```
services
    .AddIdentity<User, ApplicationRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;

        //lock out attempt
        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Then in my controller login method

```
var result = await await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, rememberMe, lockoutOnFailure);

if (result.Succeeded)
{
  return Ok();
}
```

Remember to replace true on lockoutOnFailure param

Answer (score 0):

If you have Extended the built in IdentityUser and IdentityRole to your respective Custom User and Role, then you have to Implement IUserLockoutStore On your custom UserStore and write respective code for each implementation to update your AccessFailCount.

```
public class UserStore :  IUserStore<User>, IUserEmailStore<User>, IUserPasswordStore<User>, IUserRoleStore<User> IUserLockoutStore<User>
{

    #region Other Interface Implementation
    #endregion


    #region  IUserLockoutStore

    public Task<DateTimeOffset?> GetLockoutEndDateAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        //Get user from Database and Set User LockoutEnd Date
        User user = FromDatabase(user.Id);

        return Task.FromResult(user.LockoutEnd);

    }

    public Task SetLockoutEndDateAsync(User user, DateTimeOffset? lockoutEnd, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        user.LockoutEnd = lockoutEnd;

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task<int> IncrementAccessFailedCountAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        user.AccessFailedCount += 1;

        return Task.FromResult(user.AccessFailedCount);
    }

    public Task ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        user.AccessFailedCount = 0;

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task<int> GetAccessFailedCountAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        //Get user from database and assign accessFailedCount
          User user = FromDatabase(user.Id);

        return Task.FromResult(user.accessFailedCount);
    }

    public Task<bool> GetLockoutEnabledAsync(User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        //Get user from database and assign isLockOutEnabled
        User user = FromDatabase(user.Id);

        return Task.FromResult(user.isLockOutEnabled);
    }

    public Task SetLockoutEnabledAsync(User user, bool enabled, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        user.LockoutEnabled = enabled;

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    #endregion 

    public User FromDataBase(string Id)
    {
        //Code to retrieve User from Database
    }
}
```

And in the StartUp File you have to write the following in the ConfigureService Section

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

       //Other Configurations
        services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(
            options =>
            {

                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
            }
            ).AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The "**LockoutEnabled**" prop indicates, that a user CAN be locked out. It dosnt mean the user IS currently banned.So you must Set the LockoutEnabled=true by default

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityuser-1.lockoutenabled?view=aspnetcore-2.1